# Briggs-Rauscher numerical model

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I want to use the Briggs-Rauscher experiment to demonstrate oscillating reactions, and then explain it using a numerical model.  How much is known about this reaction?  Is it possible to write down a set of differential equations for the concentrations of each chemical, and solve it to find oscillatory behaviour?

If so, what is a fairly simple but realistic set of differential equations for Briggs-Rauscher, and what are good parameters to find oscillations?

(By fairly simple I mean that it could be handled in an Excel spreadsheet or similar by talented school students.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brusselator

Comment: Is this supposed to model Briggs-Rauscher?  If so, what corresponds to A, B, D, E, X and Y in the wiki article?

Comment: See [this](http://www.math.udel.edu/~rossi/Math512/2003/br5.pdf) for detail. It contains all you need to solve your problem.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Brusselator is too simple.